# How to assert if I'm infected and how to remove

Tags: windows-7, windows, trojan, virus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

Hi all,

My computer is acting funny lately, some symtoms:
clicking things feels different. Normally I could doubleclick in chrome to select the whole URL, now I have to use CTRL-A to do that. I get the feeling something is messing with the things I select/ doubleclick. Double clicking folders doesn't open them anymore.

I have a folder on my D drive called 12bc0e0ac5b89191efaea8 with two files in it: setup.exe and setup.rll. I can't delete them, it says I don't have permission while i'm admin.

I tried Housecall from trendmicro. I couldn't select the 'I agree' tickbox with the mouse, had to use tab and spacebar, then I could not click next. 
I have AVG Free, it does not detect anything. That I find strange too, because usually it would find a few tracking cookies etc. Now, nothing, ever.

All in all I think I cought something, do you guys know of a way to check if I have and how to remove? I would hate to reinstall all I have on this box. Please advise,

Thanks in advance,

Gert-Jan

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking without more detailed information - which you seem to have troubles with in the first place, due to blocked options - it's tough to nail it down into a more specific direction.

For general help identifying what could be wrong, try installing/running the following software:

- [HijackThis from TrendMicro](http://free.antivirus.com/hijackthis/) - there's a non-installer download and you can save the logfile, could you post it so we can have a look?
- [MalwareBytes Anti-Malware](http://malwarebytes.org/) - See whether that finds something on your machine.
- [ClamWin AV](http://www.clamwin.com/) - A lot of stuff which has code to block/disable/hidefrom antivirus software seems to "forget" about this. It's a pure on-demand scanner and runs ages for me, but it has helped in a few situations.
- You could try the [bootable scanner-CD from AVG](http://www.avg.com/us-en/avg-rescue-cd), if there's something blocking AVG from properly scanning it should work if you boot from this.

Comment: Thanks, working through the list, it found some already.

Comment: Hi do you think it's possible that some infection messes with antivirus? I'm not sure if this is possible at all.

Comment: [dds.scr](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/anti-virus/dds) is a better alternative to HJT in my opinion (it looks for more stuff and in more places) but lacks any function for removing. It's just a reporting tool. It's worth a look at the logs it creates, though.

Comment: @gjvdkamp - yes, some of the better written malware specifically targets AV etc. It's quite straightforward to do.

Comment: Hmm, I ran all the tools described here, none of them found anything serious (Malwarebytes found adware and removed it). Can I now assume I'm safe? Is there anything else I can do to check if I have anything?

Comment: It's impossible to clearly say you're not infected, but if nothing found anything then as a last attempt try a bootable antivirus CD, scan with it, and if it also finds nothing it is reasonable to assume an infection isn't what's causing the issue. The next step would then be to look into software or hardware issues with the mouse, and checking the access rights on those files you cannot delete in-detail.

Answer (score 1):

Our normal recommended application is [Malware Bytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/) - use the free scanner to check your system out.

Comment: When I try to download the free version I'm forwarded to MajorGeeks.com, that looks a bit funny.. is that normal?

Comment: It may be a mirror used for storing the download files.  I get sent to http://fileforum.betanews.com/detail/Malwarebytes-AntiMalware/1186760019/1